# Move all files/directories/hidden files into directory but ignore destination directory?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

If I have a structure like:

```
parent/
  sub1/
  sub2/
  sub3/
  backup/
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  .htaccess
```

and I want to mv everything into backup/, including all directories/hidden/files etc. If I do `mv * backup/` of course I get an error because I can't move backup into itself.

How do I mv everything but ignore the destination directory in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing already actually works fine: you do get an error about moving something onto itself, but that error is harmless and doesn't stop the rest of it from working.

If you really don't like that, you can do this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name backup -execdir mv {} backup +
```

Comment: This'll try to move `.` to backup too I believe.

Comment: Is there perhaps a server or Ubuntu option for this? What my server is doing right now is moving anything before the directory itself and then stops when it gets to that point. So for example anything starting with A is moved but nothing after B. I tested on another server and it works just like you say, everything is moved (except .file) but everything after the directory goes in. Strange this work server is doing something different so I think maybe there's an option to kill all processes on error or something?

Comment: @o_O: can you edit into your answer a brief script which reproduces the behavior you're seeing where it stops when it gets to "backup"?  I was unable to reproduce it on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I am not skilled enough to do that. I know the problem server is 12.14. For now, I've just used the script you provided to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`mv` complains when you do that but it should still do what you asked. Does it not?

Also `mv *` will not move any dot files.

You would need `mv * .* backup/` for that which give you extra warning about not moving `.` and `..`.

The only way I can see to do this with the shell itself is to use `extglob` and `nullglob` and do the following.

```
$ shopt -s nullglob extglob
$ mv !(backup) .[!.]* ..?* backup/
```